# Permitir a javascript hacer vibrar un teléfono (en Android webview)

Tags: javascript, android, webview, aplicación-web

Tengo una app web que tiene un teclado virtual hecho por mi y tiene habilitada la vibración al presionar una tecla. Todo funciona perfecto en el navegador, pero en la app (que la tengo instalada en el celular) la vibración no sucede.

Nota:

1) Js está habilitado en la webview

2) La app está sincronizada con una url donde tengo colgada la app web (la cual actualizo todo el tiempo porque está en desarrollo y la testeo desde la app instalada en mi celular.

Comment: Tu aplicación es nativa o estás usando alguna herramienta que convierte tu app web en nativa tipo PhoneGap o Ionic?

Comment: Aclaré en la pregunta que es una App Web que se muestra en un webview, no que es nativa. Es solo un website con formato de diseño y comportamiento mobile para emular a una app nativa cuando se muestre a través del webview.

Comment: Entiendo, malentendí la pregunta.

Comment: No hay problema alguno.

Comment: ¿Sabés cómo habilitar el js entonces?

Answer (score 2):

En el *AndroidManifest.xml* añadir el permiso

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

Y en Java para realizar una vibración

```
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) this.context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
// Vibrate for 500 milisegundos
v.vibrate(500);
```

Respuesta extraída de [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950338/how-to-make-an-android-device-vibrate)

Para llamar un método de java con javascript, lo puedes realizar con `JavaScriptInterface`

Aquí un [ejemplo de como se usa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389572/call-java-function-from-javascript-over-android-webview)

Otra manera seria usar el framework Phonegap, que es ideono para correr aplicaciones web con un alto rendimiendo usando crosswalk "casi experiencia nativa". Además tiene un montón de plugins, como el de [vibrar](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-vibration)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Pero, ¿puedo hacer vibrar el dispositivo con tan solo el primer uses-permission? Porque la vibración viene desde un sript JavaScript que está en la web que se muestra en el webview.

Comment: O sea, no la manejo con Java ni en la mera app.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que se debe de hacer es agregar la siguiente linea de codigo dentro del Android Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

Despues de eso solo se debe de crear el metodo de vibracion dentro de la clase:

```
public void temblor(){
    Vibrator v = (Vibrator)getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    v.vibrate(1000);
}
```

Y de hay solo se debe de introducir dentro del evento o boton o funcion donde se desee ejecutar.